# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined in crud script

Tags: javascript

I don't know where my issue is on this. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

function search(){

```
    var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
    var resultsArray = data.filter(function(r){
      return r[1].indexOf(searchInput) !== -1;
    });
    var searchResultsBox = document.getElementById("searchResults");
    var templateBox = document.getElementById("rowTemplate");
    var template = templateBox.content;

    searchResultsBox.innerHTML = "";

    resultsArray.forEach(function(r){

      var tr = template.cloneNode(true);
      var eeIdColumn = tr.querySelector(".nameId");
      var firstNameColumn = tr.querySelector(".firstName");
      var lastNameColumn = tr.querySelector(".lastName");
      eeIdColumn.textContent = r[0];
      firstNameColumn.textContent = r[1];
      lastNameColumn.textContent = r[2];
      searchResultsBox.appendChild(tr);
    
    });
```

Comment: seems `data` is undefined. Where is that set?

Comment: thanks. i was able to drill down and find the issue off your suggestion